# Clean OpenVPN3 on Debian 9 fails

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, debian-stretch

I've just created a fresh `Debian 9` with `OpenVPN3` installed.

I'm getting the following error:

```
openvpn3 session-start --config server.conf

Using configuration profile from file: server.conf
Session path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/e37c3063s28d7s4233sad60s61f47ff0676d
session-start: ** ERROR ** Failed to start new session: Failed calling D-Bus method Connect: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dio_2derror_2dquark.Code36: GDBus.Error:net.openvpn.v3.sessions.error: Failed communicating with VPN backend: Failed calling D-Bus method Connect: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dio_2derror_2dquark.Code36: GDBus.Error:net.openvpn.v3.backend.error.standard: Failed executing D-Bus call 'Connect': Configuration parsing failed: option_error: remote option not specified
```

I've tried to Google the error, but without any luck - how to proceed?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Start a server? Or connect _to_ a server?

Comment: Trying to start a server.

Comment: That's not possible with OpenVPN3 at the moment (I think), it's a client only implementation.

Comment: I see, might have misunderstood openvpn. Isn't https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn also server?

Comment: No, OpenVPN **3**  is a client only implementation at the moment. You can always use OpenVPN 2.x as server and client. It's stable and secure, OVPN3 is just a "new" approach. There are plenty of tutorials and how-tos, like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-9 for OpenVPN 2.x and debian.

Comment: Ah, yes, now it works. Thank you.